# regex to find alphanumeric combination of number+text only no special

Tags: regex, plsql

have to find fix pattern of length 4 alphanumeric in input string

i have tried numeric only and alnum but cant figure out how i would only limit to char+num and no other special character or Numeric by itself

```
WITH tab AS (
    SELECT '''1234,4565,1212,7658''' AS str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '''abce,dddd,jdjd,rdrd,dder''' AS str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '''123m,d565,1dd2,7fur' AS str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '''1m@4,4u#5,1212,abcd' AS str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '''abcd,456a,d212,7658''' AS str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '''1234,4565,1212'',7658''' AS str FROM dual       
)

SELECT * FROM tab t
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t.str ,'^['']([[:alnum:]]{4},)+([[:alnum:]]{4})['']$')
AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(t.str ,'^['']([[:digit:]]{4},)+([[:digit:]]{4})['']$')
```

Expected

```
abce,dddd,jdjd,rdrd,dder
123m,d565,1dd2,7fur
```

Not expected

```
1m@4,4u#5,1212,abcd' --since this one has only 'abcd' valid but not others
abcd,456a,d212,7658  --since this one has '7658' which is invalid but others are 
1234,4565,1212 --all numeric should be ignored
```

Comment: This is going to be tough to swing using regex alone.  You should really normalize your data model, and get CSV string value onto a separate record.

Comment: try to repalce the last condition by `AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(t.str ,'[[:digit:]]{4}')`

Comment: @hotfix That won't cover all cases, or the entire CSV string.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression similar to this will capture what you have outlined in words:

```
^(([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]{3}|[[:alnum:]][[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]{2}|[[:alnum:]]{2}[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]),)*([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]{3}|[[:alnum:]][[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]{2}|[[:alnum:]]{2}[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]]{3}[[:alpha:]])$
```

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(str, '^(([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]{3}|[[:alnum:]][[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]{2}|[[:alnum:]]{2}[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]),)*([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]{3}|[[:alnum:]][[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]{2}|[[:alnum:]]{2}[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]]{3}[[:alpha:]])$', 'i');
```

However I can't work out your use of single quotes in your example, so you'll need to modify this to handle your quotes.
I would recommend updating your question to be more clear about quotes.

Also note I'm not explicitly familiar with PLSQL - written with MySQL in mind.

Answer (score 0):

All you need in the second REGEXP is ignore rows that have characters that are not alphanumeric (except comma) and number groups with a size equivalent to 4. This is necesary because Oracle does not support positive lookahead according to [this web site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html).

The solution that I propose is...

```
SELECT * FROM tab t
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t.str ,'^(([[:alnum:]]{4}),)*([[:alnum:]]{4})$')
AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(t.str ,'[^[:alnum:],]|[0-9]{4}');
```